# Can't Get Divs to render Side By Side

Tags: html, css, inline

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vhcFw/

Here's the code:

```
<div style='display:block-inline;height:100px;width:100px;background:red;'></div>
<div style='display:block-inline;height:100px;width:100px;background:blue;'></div>
```

Essentially, I cannot get the divs to render side- by side (especially when using inline styling). I realise this is a simple mistake, but I cannot figure out how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a syntax error. IT is inline-block and another thing is there would be some margin between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple syntax error.

Use `display:inline-block` not `display:block-inline`

[**Updated jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EKn6X/)

[**See MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) - display properties.

---

Alternatively, you could also float the elements.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vhcFw/3/)

Answer (score 1):

simply add float:left.to your style

```
<div style='display:block;height:100px;width:100px;background:red;float:left;'>   </div>
<div style='display:block;height:100px;width:100px;background:blue;float:left;'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here to consider. The best choice would be to use a `flex` container to surround the the elements which will by default render them side by side.

```
<div style='display:flex;'>
    <div style='height:100px;width:100px;background:red;'></div>
    <div style='height:100px;width:100px;background:blue;'></div>
</div>
```

Without a container you can just leave them to their default display which would be as `block` elements and `float` them left using `float: left;`.

```
<div style='height:100px;width:100px;background:red;float:left;'></div>
<div style='height:100px;width:100px;background:blue;float:left;'></div>
```

You can also change their display to be `inline-block` which have properties of both `inline` and `block` elements. MDN has exhaustive documentation about the [display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

```
<div style='height:100px;width:100px;background:red;display:inline-block;'></div>
<div style='height:100px;width:100px;background:blue;display:inline-block;'></div>
```